# Can anyone advise me on this ? I tried to compile using maven and got this message alongwith "Build Failure" message

Tags: maven, accumulo

Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (generate-core-thrift) on project accumulo-core: Command execution failed. Cannot run program "C:\Documents and Settings\deepak\trunk\core\src\main\thrift\thrift.sh" (in directory "C:\Documents and Settings\deepak\trunk\core"): CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application -> [Help 1]

I went to the directory trunk containing pom.xml and executed: mvn compile

I tried finding the plugin at http://maven.apache.org/plugins/ but couldn't find any .

Can anyone please explain what the problem is ? These open source things are so complex.

Comment: thrift.sh is a shell script which will never run on a windows machine. This must be running on a linux machine.

Comment: Is there any way I could run the accumulo source code on windows ?

Comment: I don't know. I can only the error message. You have to check the documentation.

Comment: If you download the current Accumulo trunk, it will compile on Windows. But there are many unit tests which will fail. Accumulo depends on Hadoop which depends on Unix. Therefore, trying to get Accumulo running unders Windows is probably not a good use of your time.

Answer (score 1):

[Apache Accumulo](http://accumulo.apache.org) does not currently support Windows in its build system. Consider using [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/), [Fedora](http://fedoraproject.org/), [CentOS](http://www.centos.org/), [Mac OSX](http://www.apple.com/mac/), or another Linux or BSD system. If you really must build in Windows, you my have luck with [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/).

Answer (score 0):

It's 2022 and we can now build [Apache Accumulo](http://accumulo.apache.org/) on Windows using [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/about).

If you want to access your Linux files from Windows, the path is:

```
\\wsl$\<DistroName>\home\<UserName>
```

Note: the above is only available when you have a WSL instance up and running.

Assuming you have a clean install of Ubuntu on WSL. Open a WSL terminal for the setup steps.

## Setup

### Install OpenJDK

Update list of available packages.

```
sudo apt update
```

Search for available JDKs.

```
apt search jdk
```

We will be installing JDK11 as Accumulo uses that.

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-11-jdk
```

Check for a successful installation.

```
java --version
```

### Configure JAVA_HOME

```
readlink -f $(which java)
```

Removing `/bin/java` from the end of the output of the above command gives us the path to the JDK.

```
nano ~/.bashrc
```

Add the following line at the bottom of the file.

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
```

Reflect changes.

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Ensure the changes are in effect.

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
```

### Install make and g++

```
sudo apt install make
sudo apt install g++
```

## Build

Clone the repo and cd to repo root.

Now build using (from WSL terminal)

```
mvn package
```

If you are using a Windows terminal (likely when using IDEs or GUI tools) [prefix `wsl`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/wsl/filesystems#run-linux-tools-from-a-windows-command-line),

```
wsl mvn package
```

Answer (score -1):

There is another description for error 193: "You may see Windows error code 193 when you are starting a Windows Share Point server or a Windows Exchange server. The error message will also generate general Service Control Manager messages in your system logs, too."

[Windows error code 193](http://error.info/windows/software-193.html)

Although it doesn't have direct answer on your problem but may be it will be also helpful for you.